# Angular2 Dependency Injection not working on service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I will let you know that I have Dependency Injection working on all of the of of the other Components and services.

Why would router ever be undefined?

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ClientQueryActionListProvider {
    constructor(
        private router: Router) {
    }


    goToCorrespondence(): void{        
        let navToRouteUrl = 'someroutehere';
        this.router.navigateByUrl(navToRouteUrl); //while debugging router is undefined 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't imagine what could cause this. Normally you can inject the router everywhere.

Comment: I have been debugging this and I have found no good logical reason for this bug. I have read many posts about this, however, most of the posts say something like you ave to add x to constructor.

Comment: can you tell me a good thing to do to debug this?

Comment: @JT1979 sorry the comment above wasn't from you. I mixed `5313M` up with `JT1979`.

Comment: why did i get voted down?

Comment: I guess because the question doesn't contain enough information to debug the problem. You could try to reproduce in a Plunker.

Comment: I was using an advanced feature of javascript in component that allows you to construct objects on the fly with the new keyword. so i wasn't passing a router into the <code>ClientQueryActionListProvider</code> which intern i wasn't using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you injected RouterModule in app.module.ts(or in current module) like below:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

If not, then import it.